# Andengine UpdateHandler

Tags: android, mobile, andengine

I'm using 2 UpdateHandlers one to add sprites with a TimerHandler set to 2 seconds and another one to delete sprites(the ones that collided) that updates on every frame. 
The problem is that the handler that should delete the sprites updates depended on the "TimerSeconds" parameter(in this case 2 seconds). So if I set the TimerSeconds to something like 10s than the collided sprites dont get deleted.

```
this.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(2f,true, new ITimerCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

            final FixtureDef PLAYER_FIX = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(25.0f, 1.0f, 0.25f);
            Sprite redBombSprite = new Sprite(SceneManager.CAMERA_WIDTH/2,SceneManager.CAMERA_HEIGHT/8,bombTextureRegion,engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            redBombSprite.setX(redBombSprite.getX()-redBombSprite.getWidth()/2);
            redBombSprite.setY(redBombSprite.getY()-redBombSprite.getHeight()/2);
            redBombSprite.setRotation(35.0f);
            attachChild(redBombSprite);
            float x = MathUtils.random(-600f,600f);
            float y = MathUtils.random(-600f,600f);
            Vector2 impulse = new Vector2(x,y);
            Body redBomb = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, redBombSprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, PLAYER_FIX);

            redBomb.setAttachedSprite(redBombSprite);
            redBomb.applyLinearImpulse(impulse, redBomb.getPosition());
            redBomb.setUserData("bomb");


            redBombs.add(redBomb);
            physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(redBombSprite, redBomb, true, true));

            }

        }));
```

delete collided sprites:

```
public IUpdateHandler getCollisionUpdateHandler(){
        return new IUpdateHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

            for(int i=0;i<redBombs.size()-1;i++) {
                if(redBombs.get(i).getAttachedSprite().isDelete()){
                    final Sprite Object = redBombs.get(i).getAttachedSprite();
                    redBombs.remove(i);
                    final Body body = physicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findBodyByShape(Object);
                    physicsWorld.destroyBody(body);
                    detachChild(Object);

                }

            }

            }
```

Thank you in advance, and sorry for the convoluted code.

Answer (score 1):

For checking sprite collision, use collidesWith() method like sprite1.collidesWith(sprite2)

Use above method in TimeHandler. Depending upon time pass (2f or 10f as per your requirement)
collidesWith method run.. So you can delete sprite after some seconds..

Comment: I'm using ContactListener for collision detection. The second UpdateHandler just deletes them from the list and the physicsworld. The problem I'm having is that they dont get deleted when ever the new frame updates, they get deleted with only when the other timer ticks.